# Load property from external file into build.gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle, build.gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have this:

```
def loadProperties(String sourceFileName) {
    def config = new Properties()
    def propFile = new File(sourceFileName)
    if (propFile.canRead()) {
        config.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))
        for (Map.Entry property in config) {
            ext[property.key] = property.value;
        }
    }
}

loadProperties 'gradle.properties'
```

How do I reference the property (ndk.dir) in build.gradle?

```
def ndkBuild = new File("$ndk.dir", 'ndk-build')
```

And is there a better way of reading ndk.dir from file gradle.properties?
And how do I use it in?

```
def ndkBuild = new File("$ndk.dir", 'ndk-build')
```

Full code:

```
task buildNative(type: Exec) {
    loadProperties 'gradle.properties'
    if (System.getenv('NDK_HOME') != null || "$ndk.dir" != null) {
        if ("$ndk.dir" != null) {
            def ndkBuild = new File("$ndk.dir", 'ndk-build')
        } else {
            def ndkBuild = new File(System.getenv('NDK_HOME'), 'ndk-build')
        }
        workingDir "jni"
        executable ndkBuild
    } else {
        throw new GradleException('Reason: NDK_HOME not set or ndk.dir is missing in gradle.properties...')
    }
}

def loadProperties(String sourceFileName) {
    def config = new Properties()
    def propFile = new File(sourceFileName)
    if (propFile.canRead()) {
        config.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))
        for (Map.Entry property in config) {
            ext[property.key] = property.value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please always describe *exactly* what the problem is, what error message you get, etc.

Comment: The problem is that "$ndk.dir" does not work, I assume I use it wrong?

Comment: That's not an exact description. What exact error message do you get? Etc.

Comment: * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':primavista-android-reloaded'.
> Could not find property 'ndk' on task ':primavista-android-reloaded:buildNative'.

Comment: Updated question with full sample aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like `ndk.dir`, `"$ndk.dir"` first gets the `ndk` property, and then the `dir` property, which is not what you want. (This is also evident in the error message, which says "Could not find property 'ndk'".) Instead, this should work:

```
def ndkBuild = new File(project.property('ndk.dir'), 'ndk-build')
```

A safer solution is to store the whole `Properties` object as a single extra property:

```
...
ext.externalProps = config
```

Then you can access external properties like so:

```
def ndkBuild = new File(externalProps['ndk.dir'], 'ndk-build')
```